# How do we know that $0*f'(x)=0$ in this classic proof of continuity?

Tags: calculus

In the attached proof of how differentiability implies continuity, what if $f'(x)$ outputs an undefined value, such as if $f'(x)=\frac{x}{0}$? This would make $0*\text{undefined}=\text{undefined}$, not $0$. Would this ever happen? If $f'(x)$ exists, is there any guarantee that its range is defined for all values in its domain? (this spot is underlined in red in the attached proof).
[image]

Comment: $0$ times any number is $0$.

Comment: $f'(x)$ is the slope of the tangent line at the point $(x,f(x))$ and is thus a finite number.

Comment: The assumption of the theorem is precisely that the $f'(x)$ is not undefined.

Comment: $x$ is a single fixed value throughout this proof. We don't care whether or not $f'(x)$ exists anywhere else in the domain of $f$. They probably should have written '$x_0$' to emphasize that.

Comment: You can deal with the $h=0$ case separately, since then $f(x+h)=f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement of the result to be proved begins with

> Let $f$ be a function having a derivative $f’(x)$ at $x$.

This means that $f’(x)$ is defined and is equal to a real number. The author added this clause to avoid the case where $f’(x)$ is undefined.

We only need $f’$ to be defined at $x$ for the proof to work. There is no need to worry about whether $f$ is differentiable at any other value.